# OpenGL GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP creating grid with degenerate triangles / for one draw call

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es2

I need to create a grid ready for GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP rendering with **One** drawcall - so i need to degenerate the triangles.

I am almost there but missing last row/column and can't figure out why.

My **grid** is just a :

- Position ( self explanatory )
- Size ( the x,y size )
- Resolution ( the spacing between each vertex in x,y )

Here is the method used to create verts/indices and return them:

```
int iCols = vSize.x / vResolution.x;
int iRows = vSize.y / vResolution.y;


// Create Vertices
for(int y = 0; y <= iRows; y ++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x <= iCols; x ++)
    {
        float startu  = (float)x / (float)vSize.x;
        float startv  = (float)y / (float)vSize.y; 


        tControlVertex.Color    = vColor;
        tControlVertex.Position = CVector3(x * vResolution.x,y * vResolution.y,0);
        tControlVertex.TexCoord = CVector2(startu, startv - 1.0 );

        vMeshVertices.push_back(tControlVertex);   
    }
}


// Create Indices
rIndices.clear();

for (int r = 0; r < iRows - 1; r++)
{
    rIndices.push_back(r*iCols);

    for (int c = 0; c < iCols; c++)
    {
        rIndices.push_back(r*iCols+c);
        rIndices.push_back((r+1)*iCols+c);
    }
    rIndices.push_back((r + 1) * iCols + (iCols - 1));
}
```

And to visualise that, few examples first.

1) Size 512x512 Resolution 64x64, so it should be made of 8 x 8 quads, but i get 7x7 only

[image]

2) Size 512x512 Resolution 128x128, so it should be made of 4 x 4 quads, but i get 3x3 only

[image]

3) Size 128x128 Resolution 8x8 so it should be made of 16 x 16 quads but i get 15x15 only

[image]

So as you can see, i am missing the Last Row and Last Column somewhere.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have solved this. 
I think we're all getting old, that's why we couldn't spot it.

Here is the code:

```
    // Create Vertices
// Notice <= to create exactly as many vertices in X and Y as required
for(int y = 0; y <= iRows ; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x <= iCols; x++)
    {
        float u  = (float)x / (float)vSize.x;
        float v  = (float)y / (float)vSize.y;

        tControlVertex.Color    = vColor;
        tControlVertex.Position = CVector3(x * vResolution.x, y * vResolution.y,0);
        tControlVertex.TexCoord = CVector2(u, v - 1.0 );

        vMeshVertices.push_back(tControlVertex);   
    }

}


// Create Indices
rIndices.clear();

// Create Indices with degenerate triangles ( stitching )
// Notice < iRows, <= iCols
for (int y = 0; y < iRows; y++)
{
    // Degenerate first triangle in this column
    rIndices.push_back((unsigned short)((y + 0) * (iCols+1) + 0));

    for (int x = 0; x < iCols + 1; x++)
    {
        // Vertex in actual row
        rIndices.push_back((unsigned short)((y + 0) * (iCols+1) + x));

        // Vertex row below
        rIndices.push_back((unsigned short)((y + 1) * (iCols+1) + x));
    }

    // Degenerate last triangle in this column
    rIndices.push_back((unsigned short)((y + 0) * (iCols+1) + iCols+1));
}
```

And the results are:

512x512 with Resolution of 64x64 ( called stepping ) produces 8*64 x 8*64 = 512x512.

[image]

Thanks CiscoIPPhone for looking into this.

Answer (score 2):

If iCols is 10, then 11 horizontal vertices are created:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= iCols; x ++)
```

When creating the last column of indices you do:

```
rIndices.push_back((r + 1) * iCols + (iCols - 1));
```

We can ignore the first part to just concentrate on a single row:

```
rIndices.push_back(iCols - 1);
```

(iCols - 1) would be 9, so it's not going to address the last vertex (10). I think to fix the problem with columns you should remove the -1.

To fix the problem with the amount of rows change

```
(int r = 0; r < iRows - 1; r++)
```

to

```
(int r = 0; r < iRows; r++)
```

Because the difference between y <= iRows; and r < iRows - 1 is two, but there should only be one more vertical vertex than there are rows.

Comment: +1 Rule of thumb: Are you simultaneously dealing with the notion of both tiles and vertices? It's probably an off-by-one error.

Comment: CiscoIPPhone, unfortunately it does not work..

The code with your suggestions:
http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/44b05342.png

The results:
http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/6c54ac19.png

Comment: Try changing the `rIndices.push_back(iCols);` to `rIndices.push_back((r + 1) * iCols + iCols));` I was just ignoring the first part of that line so it was easier to work out the last vertex addressed.

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone

Results: http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/06a4a8a6.png
Code: http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/e19e52e8.png

Still nothing..

Comment: @PeeS I think there are still some off by one errors. For example `rIndices.push_back(r*iCols);` is going to have the same index as `rIndices.push_back(r*iCols+c);` when c is 0.

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone, i'm trying to find out how to index from the beggining.. seems like a small stupid mistake somewhere..

Comment: Actually, ignore my last comment. That is what you would want to happen if you're making degenerate triangles between the rows, so the problem is elsewhere. I'll take another look later.

Comment: Yes i repeat to degenerate the triangles as you have noticed, still ooking to find out how to index that mesh... incredible i can't figure it out ..

Thanks for looking into this mate.